# High resolution images aren't displaying on iPhone on a Website I built & 3 images aren't on the width it should be

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm facing a problem on a website I built , there is a photo on the contact page , which works on MacOSX , Windows , but not on iPhone 4/5/4s and etc..
Picture details:

```
Dimensions 3508 × 2480
File size 320 KB
MIME type image/jpeg
```

The picture just doesn't appear on the Iphone , maybe it's because of the resolution ? 320 KB is the minimum size I'm able to go because it's not that heavy to load and the quality is great. Hope it can be solved in any way, there's the code of calling the image:

```
<img src="/styles/Images/contact.jpg" alt="something" title="something" style="max-width: 100%;">
```

---

The second problem which is the most important is the main page, In any screen it displays 3 pictures in a row , but in iPhone the width is too much , so you can only see 2 pictures and a litle bit of the 3rd.
Im using  for the website , there is no need an optimized version for mobile , just same website but smaller , though the Images aren't displayed on 100% of the mobile width, you can only see 2 and abit of the 3rd image.

```
    <div id="container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;margin: 0 auto;">
<table style='position:relative;margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;'>
 <tr>
     <td><a href="/styles/Images/SLone.jpg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
     <img src='/styles/Images/SLone.jpg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
     </a>
     </td>
     <td>
     <a href="/styles/Images/SLtwo.jpeg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
     <img src='/styles/Images/SLtwo.jpeg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
     </a>
     </td>
    <td>
    <a href="/styles/Images/SLthree.jpeg" data-lightbox="true" title="NF NOYA FIEBER">
    <img src='/styles/Images/SLthree.jpeg' width='395px' height='592px' alt='NF Noya Fieber נויה פיבר'/>
    </a>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this webpage:

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-maximum-image-size/

Also I have come across before safari and some webservers require the filename to be 100% right, whilst I had found on PC are more forgiving, I use a NAS box as a test for ios devices and come across this before..

Comment: Didn't work , I resized the pictures so it fits on all devices ( 1705x1205) still doesn't show up.